# Необязательное поле в Json классе

Tags: c#, json, json.net

У меня есть `json`, который я десериализую

```
 public class Item
        {
            public int bot { get; set; }
            public Item1[] items { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public float price { get; set; }

        }
```

Все десериализуется отлично, однако есть такие случаи, когда поля `price` нет. 
`NewtonsoftJson` автоматом присваивает ему значение 0. Как сделать чтобы он туда записывал значение по умолчанию. Т.е. если поля нет - то ставим значение 0.

Comment: 0 -- это и есть значение по умолчанию для `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewtonsoftJson` не ставит ему автоматом `0`. Это при создании объекта значение свойства `price` задается `0` по дефолту. Если хотите задать дефолтное значение для создаваемого объекта, сделайте это в конструкторе этого объекта.

```
public class Item
{
    public int bot { get; set; } // int - 0 по дефолту
    public Item1[] items { get; set; } // [] - null по дефолту
    public string name { get; set; } // string - null по дефолту
    public float price { get; set; } // float - 0 по дефолту (изменяем в конструкторе)

    public Item()
    {
        price = 99999; // задали другое значение
    }
}
```

Как верно заметил @Андрей, начиная с `C# 6.0` можно писать так:

```
public float price { get; set; } = 99999;
```

В итоге такая запись развернется в конструкцию с конструктором при компиляции.

[Пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LI2k32)!

Comment: Лучше продублировать код в ответе.

Comment: @andreycha согласен.

Comment: @Андрей можно. Обновился.